# Android. How to operate by history stack?

Tags: android

Questions
1. How to make the same functionality as physical button "Back" on android phone?
2. Is it possible to make "Next" button using android history stack? I understand that probably it is not possible, but may be yes. So please let me know exactly

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:
Just call `finish()`

Question 2:
I'm not sure about this. But I think when you call finish the Activity gets removed from the history stack. If you want something like next you could start the Activities using `startActivityForResult()` and then use `onActivityResult()` to determine that the user hit back/you finished the activity and save that somehow.